# problem with my face recognition program

Tags: c#

Currently im doing a program on face recognition but i've met with problems.
Below is my coding for my program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using OpenCvSharp;

namespace OpenCvSharp
{
    class Program 
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            //
            // Validate that OpenCV DLLs are properly loaded
            //
            using ( IplImage image = new IplImage( 128 , 128 , BitDepth.U8 , 1 ) ) 
            {
                image.Zero();
                image.DrawCircle( new CvPoint( 64 , 64 ) , 32 , CvColor.White , 4 );
                using ( CvWindow window = new CvWindow( image ) )
                {
                    CvWindow.WaitKey();
                }
            }

            //
            // Intitialize variables required to reproduce the access violation error
            //
            using ( CvMat intrinsicMatrix0    = Cv.CreateMat( 3 , 3 , MatrixType.F32C1 ) ) 
            using ( CvMat intrinsicMatrix1    = Cv.CreateMat( 3 , 3 , MatrixType.F32C1 ) )
            using ( CvMat distortionCoeffs0   = Cv.CreateMat( 5 , 1 , MatrixType.F32C1 ) ) 
            using ( CvMat distortionCoeffs1   = Cv.CreateMat( 5 , 1 , MatrixType.F32C1 ) )
            using ( CvMat rotation            = Cv.CreateMat( 3 , 3 , MatrixType.F64C1 ) )
            using ( CvMat translation         = Cv.CreateMat( 3 , 1 , MatrixType.F64C1 ) )
            using ( CvMat rectifiedRodriguez0 = Cv.CreateMat( 3 , 3 , MatrixType.F64C1 ) )
            using ( CvMat rectifiedRodriguez1 = Cv.CreateMat( 3 , 3 , MatrixType.F64C1 ) )
            using ( CvMat rectifiedIntrinsic0 = Cv.CreateMat( 3 , 4 , MatrixType.F64C1 ) )
            using ( CvMat rectifiedIntrinsic1 = Cv.CreateMat( 3 , 4 , MatrixType.F64C1 ) )
            {
                CvSize imageSize = new CvSize( 640 , 480 );

                intrinsicMatrix0[0,0] = 533.1;
                intrinsicMatrix0[0,1] = 0;
                intrinsicMatrix0[0,2] = 343.6;
                intrinsicMatrix0[1,0] = 0;
                intrinsicMatrix0[1,1] = 533.0;
                intrinsicMatrix0[1,2] = 236.1;
                intrinsicMatrix0[2,0] = 0;
                intrinsicMatrix0[2,1] = 0;
                intrinsicMatrix0[2,2] = 1;

                intrinsicMatrix1[0,0] = 535.4;
                intrinsicMatrix1[0,1] = 0;
                intrinsicMatrix1[0,2] = 328.2;
                intrinsicMatrix1[1,0] = 0;
                intrinsicMatrix1[1,1] = 534.6;
                intrinsicMatrix1[1,2] = 249.8;
                intrinsicMatrix1[2,0] = 0;
                intrinsicMatrix1[2,1] = 0;
                intrinsicMatrix1[2,2] = 1;

                distortionCoeffs0[0] = -0.27621;
                distortionCoeffs0[1] =  0.05675;
                distortionCoeffs0[2] =  0.00124;
                distortionCoeffs0[3] = -0.00023;
                distortionCoeffs0[4] = -0.02399;

                distortionCoeffs1[0] = -0.29628;
                distortionCoeffs1[1] =  0.17210;
                distortionCoeffs1[2] = -0.00103;
                distortionCoeffs1[3] =  0.00095;
                distortionCoeffs1[4] = -0.10036;

                rotation[0,0] =  0.999977;
                rotation[0,1] =  0.003385;
                rotation[0,2] =  0.005721;
                rotation[1,0] = -0.003353;
                rotation[1,1] =  0.999979;
                rotation[1,2] = -0.005464;
                rotation[2,0] = -0.005739;
                rotation[2,1] =  0.005445;
                rotation[2,2] =  0.999968;

                translation[0] = -81.94;
                translation[1] =   1.13;
                translation[2] =  -1.08;

                Cv.StereoRectify( 
                    intrinsicMatrix0  , intrinsicMatrix1 , 
                    distortionCoeffs0 , distortionCoeffs1 , 
                    imageSize , 
                    rotation , translation , 
                    rectifiedRodriguez0 , rectifiedRodriguez1 , 
                    rectifiedIntrinsic0 , rectifiedIntrinsic1 );
                Cv.WaitKey( 0 );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've met with problems like:
1. the type or namespace name was not found
2. the name does not exist

Can someone pls help me? Thanks.

Comment: What namespace?  If it is external have you added references to the exteral libraries in your project?

Answer (score 1):

Going to go out on a limb here and say your project does not reference the OpenCvSharp project (or the equivelent .dll file).

Answer (score 1):

you need to add reference to required dlls, follow the tutorial below

http://code.google.com/p/opencvsharp/wiki/Tutorial_Windows

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bit weird that you're putting your code in the openCVSharp namespace
generally, you need to do 2 things:

- In the project explorer, under References, you need to add reference and point to where your OpenCVSharp.dll is.
- Copy the OpenCVSharp.dll into your working directory (not sure this is necessary but that's what we did in class)

Remember also that opencvsharp is just a wrapper so it needs the OpenCV C++ libraries. I copied all the OpenCV dll from the bin folder of OpenCV to the project's executable folder (in my case the debug/ folder)